# WPF the textblock background color can't binding variable

Tags: c#, wpf

Excuse me.I am a noob.I want click the button to change the background's color of textblock. the value of variable can change ,but the background's color didn't change.There is my code.please help me.

Visual studio 2017

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/126wQ.png)

WPF

the TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Width="75" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="205,187,626,468" FontSize="48">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">

                <Setter Property="Text" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TestView,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

and the Button

`<Button Margin="202,596,564,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Click="buttonClick">
</Button>`

Xaml.cs

```
private bool testView = true;
    public bool TestView
    {
        get { return testView; }
        set { testView = value; }
    }

    private void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestView = false;
    }
```

I expect when testView == true,the background's color of textblock is Green when testView == false,the background's color of textblock is Red.
and the Text is in the middle of TextBlock

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Window (View) is not getting updated is because you need to notify it of a change. To do this in WPF, you must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and set the DataContext accordingly. Typically, this should be done using the MVVM design pattern, but for the sake of answering your question, here's how to do it with your current setup:

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool testView = true;
        public bool TestView
        {
            get { return testView; }
            set 
            { 
                if (testView != value)
                {
                    testView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TestView");
                }
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestView = false;
        }

        #region INotify
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion INotify
    }
```

Comment: @xeroxion can you please accept this as the answer =]

Comment: sorry,I am been busy recently.I test immediately